# Argument is of length zero when reading line by line R

Tags: r

I am trying to read a txt file R and parse it.

The code looks as such:

```
con <- file(inputFileName,"r")
mm_data<- readLines(con,warn = FALSE)
for (i in 1:length(mm_data)){
    dataline = mm_data[i]
    if(length(dataline) & grep("PACKAGE",dataline) & grep("PACKAGE REQUIREMENT", dataline))
    {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

Some lines are empty adn i get "argument is of length zero" error. How to avoid this?

Comment: this can occur when the output from one of the arguments is `logical(0)`. One of my least favourite things about R. Go through and remove each of the arguments and see which one is causing the issues

Comment: How about change from ``grep`` to ``grepl``, which returns logical... Also u might benefit processing the vector as a whole instead of iterating over it, depending on task.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is the use of `length()` instead of `nchar()`.  Since `dataline` is an element of `mm_data`, it is always length 1.  To count the number of characters in it, use `nchar()` instead.

Another problem is the use of `grep()`.  It will return the index of a match, not a logical value.  If your line doesn't match the pattern, it returns a length zero vector, and that's why you get the error you saw.  If you want a logical result, use `grepl()`.

A third problem is that you never close the connection.  This isn't going to cause an error, but it could cause you to run out of connections if this code is in a loop, or you run it a lot for some other reason.

A final problem is a little obscure:  if you happen to read a file that has no lines in it, then `length(mm_data)` will end up as `0`.  Your loop will still run
through two steps because `1:0` is like `c(1, 0)`.

Not a problem, but an inefficiency:  if your line matches the pattern `"PACKAGE REQUIREMENT"`, then it will also match the pattern `"PACKAGE"` and will not be a blank line.  So you really only need one `grepl()` in the test.

A version of the code that incorporates all of these suggestions would be:

```
mm_data<- readLines(inputFileName, warn = FALSE)
for (i in seq_along(mm_data)){
    dataline <- mm_data[i]
    if(grepl("PACKAGE REQUIREMENT", dataline))
    {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```